# What effect does replacing the load on a switch-mode power supply with a battery have on design?

Tags: battery-charging, dc-dc-converter

I am working through a theoretical design for a solar charge controller for a battery bank where the battery voltage is strictly greater than the open circuit voltage of the solar array.

Most of the explanations of switch-mode power (a boost converter in this case) treat the load as a simple resistive load. I'm trying to understand what happens when the load produces its own voltage potential. Are there modifications needed to prevent the battery from feeding back into the inductor or discharging when not being charged?

Comment: Charging from a solar array is a complicated subject if you want to do it right.  There's MPPT to extract the maximum power from the panels, current/voltage/charge termination control to charge the batteries properly, thermal monitoring and control during charging and safety features to avoid bad things like fires and explosions.  (Especially for lithium batteries, Lead acid is a little more forgiving.) So if you're asking a question like this it seems like you should find an off the shelf MPPT charge controller for your batteries rather than trying to design something.

Comment: Let's confine our conversation just to the DC-DC converter part of the circuit please. As I said this is an academic exercise at this point. You may assume a simple current source and an ideal battery if you wish.

Comment: OK got it.  In that case in the absence of any other system specs, a non-synchronous boost will not conduct current in the opposite direction so that's the easy way to go.  If it doesn't meet your efficiency target (as of yet unspecified) then you need to use a synchronous boost and a control scheme to detect reverse current and shut off the synchronous FET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a really rough conceptual model of your system (in a real switcher SW1 would be a FET).  The important thing to note is that if D1 is really a diode, then it simply won't conduct backwards.

To gain efficiency, modern switching converters use FETs for both the switch and the diode, in which case the thing could back-conduct from the battery to the solar cell -- but you could take care of that in your control circuitry.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frb6dd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In any transmitter or charger circuit,  the **maximum power transfer** MPT depends on matching the complex impedances. The reactances may fall out here.

- starting off with a lower PV voltage than battery is a poor start.

The simplest unregulated solution is a battery float voltage that matches 85% of Voc. Then a LED load to prevent overvoltage or BMS.

This requires matching the impedance and voltage of the source to the load.

A battery is at least 10kF and ESR <100 mohm for 1 Li Ion cell fully charged to 3.8V.  (Until its dead that is) Thus as the battery charges up from low SoC, it quickly reduces in ESR to the <<100 mOhm as C increases until 3.5 or so then stays constant. [AFAICR]

I believe  they use 4.2 to speed up the secondary charge (double layer charge effect) for the last 10% capacity which has a slower time constant then cutoff when drops below x% of the rapid CC rate.

If you use a boost regulator at some f the battery is again like a short circuit as it charges up above its voltage and the input impedance must match the available source impedance of the solar controlled current source at <=85% Voc.

In other words , what is the present solar power Z=Voc/Isc and match f with that using ZL(f)=2pif L*d.f for duty factor , d.f. and short circuit current , Isc.

it is possible to model a semiconductor cct  impedance and voltage to match any given PV in daylight, without using a MPPT design,  but those generally hunt for MPT.